# Flex printjob crashes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, crash, flash-builder

i'm trying to print data from a datagrid with the flex printjob. in the grid are about 40 lines filled with data.

However, when i try to print, the app crashes, but some pages were printed.

here is my code:

```
protected function openPrintDialogMonth():void {
                doPrintingMonth();
        }
        protected function doPrintingMonth():void {
            var printjob2:FlexPrintJob;
            var printTemplate:printTemplate = new printTemplate();
            var printDataGrid:PrintDataGrid;


            printjob2 = new FlexPrintJob();
            if( printjob2.start() )
            {
                var currentYear:Date = new Date();

                var dataArray:Array = new Array();
                trace( "Width/Height:", printjob2.pageWidth, "/", printjob2.pageHeight );

                printDataGrid = new PrintDataGrid();
                printTemplate.width = 1368;
                printTemplate.height = 800;


                printTemplate.data = gridReport.dataProvider;
                printTemplate.editData();

                printTemplate.year = String(currentYear.getFullYear());

                printTemplate.printDataGrid.columns = gridReport.columns;
                printTemplate.printDataGrid.columnWidth = gridReport.columnWidth;
                printTemplate.printDataGrid.visible = true;
                printTemplate.printDataGrid.showHeaders = true;
                printTemplate.printDataGrid.sizeToPage = true;

                printTemplate.scaleX = 1.00;

                printTemplate.validateNow();

                this.addElement( printTemplate );



                if( !printTemplate.printDataGrid.validNextPage ) 
                {
                    printjob2.addObject( printTemplate,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
                    this.removeElement( printTemplate );
                }
                else 
                {
                    printjob2.addObject( printTemplate,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);
                    this.removeElement( printTemplate );

                    while( true ) 
                    {
                        printTemplate.printDataGrid.nextPage();
                        printjob2.addObject( printTemplate,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH);

                        if( !printTemplate.printDataGrid.validNextPage )
                            break;
                    }
                }

                printjob2.send();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When the app "crashes" do any errors occur, have you verified you're using the flash player debug player in your browser.

Comment: i'm using the print function in adobe air. if the print file is longer, only some pages appear

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today in Flash with Adobe Air. In my case I had to add the displayobject to the stage first before starting the print job. Adding it to the displaylist forces a redraw which is probably needed for the printjob.